How to Transform a PSBall into Other Shapes
Consider the code which compiles with XeLaTeX:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{scalefnt,scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold2}{RGB}{249,215,73}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
\psBall(0,0){PureGold2!85!DarkRed}{2.5cm}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}

and which produces the output:

I would like, if possible, to transform the above psball into a different shape by either a vertical or horizontal stretch (or concatenation). Applying \vstretch does not work. And, if the ball were an includegraphics, one could assign a width and length to the incoming image to distort it a little.
QUESTION: How may one do similarly to the above ball?

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold2}{RGB}{249,215,73}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
  \psscalebox{1 2}{%
    \psBall(0,0){PureGold2!85!DarkRed}{2.5cm}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}


